# How to create and append to a hdf5 table using pandas with cells containing numpy arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, hdf5

I want to create a h5 database with 3 columns, `x: np.array`, `y: int32`, `z: np.array`. But I keep getting strange errors.

```
store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
df['y'] = df['y'].astype(np.int32)

for i in range(10):
    arr = np.random.randn(3, 3)
    df = df.append({'x': arr, 'y': 1, 'z': arr}, ignore_index=True)

store.append('df', df)
```

This gives the error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

It isn't related to the integer `y` column as I've tried this with 3 arrays instead, same error. I've been over the docs many times but still no idea what I'm doing wrong. Hopefully one of you nice folks can help.

Comment: Writing directly to an `h5` works: `df.to_hdf('pdtest.h5','df')`.  It gives me a performance warning, saying has to `pickle` some items (the arrays), but that's ok.  `pd.read_hdf` works fine.  To my surprise I can even load the values with `h5py`.

Comment: Yes that does work as does `store['df'] = df` and `store.put('df', df)` but these all use the fixed format for the hdf5 file which doesn't allow appending more data to it later, which I need. Specifying `format='table'` in any of these gives the same error as before.

Comment: The code comment just above the error line says `## we cannot serialize this data, so report an exception on a column`.  In the `fixed` format is uses `pickle` (aka `np.save`) to serialize the array elements.  Apparently it can't or won't do so with the `table` format.  With `table` the `h5` layout is quite different

Answer (score 1):

Writing your simple column (twice for fun) to file with `table`:

```
In [514]: df[['y','y']].to_hdf('pdtest.h5','df', format='table')                         
In [515]: df1 = pd.read_hdf('pdtest.h5')                                                 
In [516]: df1                                                                            
Out[516]: 
   y  y
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  1  1
4  1  1
5  1  1
6  1  1
7  1  1
8  1  1
9  1  1
```

Looking at it with `h5py`:

```
In [517]: f=h5py.File('pdtest.h5','r')                                                   
In [518]: f.keys()                                                                       
Out[518]: <KeysViewHDF5 ['df']>
In [519]: f['df'].keys()                                                                 
Out[519]: <KeysViewHDF5 ['_i_table', 'table']>
In [521]: f['df/table']                                                                  
Out[521]: <HDF5 dataset "table": shape (10,), type "|V24">
In [522]: f['df/table'][:]                                                               
Out[522]: 
array([(0, [1, 1]), (1, [1, 1]), (2, [1, 1]), (3, [1, 1]), (4, [1, 1]),
       (5, [1, 1]), (6, [1, 1]), (7, [1, 1]), (8, [1, 1]), (9, [1, 1])],
      dtype=[('index', '<i8'), ('values_block_0', '<i8', (2,))])
```

It has save the 'table' as a numpy structured array.

In `fixed`:

```
In [525]: df[['y']].to_hdf('pdtest.h5','df', format='fixed')                             
In [526]: df1 = pd.read_hdf('pdtest.h5')      
In [528]: f=h5py.File('pdtest.h5','r')                                                   
In [529]: f.keys()                                                                       
Out[529]: <KeysViewHDF5 ['df']>
In [530]: f['df'].keys()                                                                 
Out[530]: <KeysViewHDF5 ['axis0', 'axis1', 'block0_items', 'block0_values']>
```

or back to saving the whole dataframe:

```
In [539]: df.to_hdf('pdtest.h5','df')                                                    
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:2505: PerformanceWarning: 
your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot
map directly to c-types [inferred_type->mixed,key->block1_values] [items->Index(['x', 'z'], dtype='object')]

  encoding=encoding,
In [540]: f.close()                                                                      
In [541]: f=h5py.File('pdtest.h5','r')                                                   
In [542]: f.keys()                                                                       
Out[542]: <KeysViewHDF5 ['df']>
In [543]: f['df'].keys()                                                                 
Out[543]: <KeysViewHDF5 ['axis0', 'axis1', 'block0_items', 'block0_values', 'block1_items', 'block1_values']>
```

Apparently the two blocks consists of columns with distinct storage requirements.

The simple column:

```
In [546]: f['df/block0_items'][:]                                                        
Out[546]: array([b'y'], dtype='|S1')
In [547]: f['df/block0_values'][:]                                                       
Out[547]: 
array([[1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1]])
```

And the array columns, which it has deduced contain the same array, which it has stored as an object dtype array, containing one array:

```
In [548]: f['df/block1_items'][:]                                                        
Out[548]: array([b'x', b'z'], dtype='|S1')
In [549]: f['df/block1_values'][:]                                                       
Out[549]: 
array([array([128,   4, 149, ..., 148,  98,  46], dtype=uint8)],
      dtype=object)
```

Hopefully this clarifies why `pandas` cannot save your dataframe with the `table` format. `HDF5` has its own storage layout.  `h5py` is a relatively low level interface to `HDF5`, with `numpy` arrays at the Python end (apparently the match is fairly close and transparent).  `pandas` adds another layer on top of that.